# Wordpress Loop within Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which is a loop within a loop, the second loop is dynamic and uses the current pages title `get_the_title();

The problem I have is that it doesn't work and I think its because `get_the_title();` from the original loop is being overwritten in the second loop.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if(get_field( 'artist_photo')) { $image=g et_field( 'artist_photo'); } ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

  <header>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <hr />
  </header>

  <div class="content">

    <?php if(!empty($image)) { echo "<img src='" . $image[ 'url'] . "' alt='" . $image[ 'alt'] . "' class='featured' />"; } ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <hr />
    <h2>Artwork for Sale</h2>
    <?php $args=a rray( 'post_type'=>'artwork', 'meta_key' => 'artist', 'meta_value' => the_title() ); $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul id="related-artwork" class="row">

      <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

      <li class="col-sm-3">

        <?php if(get_field( 'image')) { $image=g et_field( 'image'); } ?>
        <?php if(!empty($image)) { echo "<img src='" . $image[ 'url'] . "' alt='" . $image[ 'alt'] . "' />"; } ?>

        <div class="info">
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        </div>

      </li>


      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </ul>
    <?php else : ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


  </div>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: any error is there?

Comment: The two answers below are correct but this question doesn't belong here. It belongs in the [wordpress stack exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue at the

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'artwork',
'meta_key'      => 'artist',
'meta_value'    => the_title()
    );
```

because the_title() is not a returned value but echoed **get_the_title()** .

**So, replace the 'meta_value'  => the_title() line with 'meta_value'   => get_the_title()**.

Also, at the second loop, remember to call **$the_query->the_post();** within the while loop, to make the switch.

Something like :

```
<ul id="related-artwork" class="row">

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

 $the_query->the_post();

    <li class="col-sm-3">
    .....
```

The Two edits should do the  trick I think. Everything else seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wp_reset_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) instead of [wp_reset_query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query).

> Calling wp_reset_query is not necessary after using WP_Query or
>   get_posts as these don't modify the main query object. Instead use
>   wp_reset_postdata